# Matrix notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I have the following equation:

$\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_2 = D_2(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi^T_{G_{21}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\Delta \delta_e & \Phi^T_{G_{22}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0) \Delta \delta_a & \Phi^T_{G_{23}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0) \Delta \delta_r
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta_{G_{21}} \\ 
\Theta_{G_{22}}\\ 
\Theta_{G_{23}}
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_2$ is size $3\times 1$, where $D_2$ is $3\times 3$, where $\Phi^T_{G_{2\star}}$ is $3\times 6$, where $\Delta \delta_\star$ are scalars and where $\Theta_{G_{2\star}}$ is $6\times 1$.

This equation is valid at every time instance, so I want to write the following set of equations:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_{2,1}\\ 
\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_{2,2}\\ 
\vdots\\ 
\Delta \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_{2,N}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
D_2(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\\ 
D_2(\boldsymbol{x}_1)\\ 
\vdots\\
D_2(\boldsymbol{x}_N)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi^T_{G_{21}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\Delta \delta_{e,1} & \Phi^T_{G_{22}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0) \Delta \delta_{a,1} & \Phi^T_{G_{23}}(\boldsymbol{x}_0) \Delta \delta_{r,1} \\ 
\Phi^T_{G_{21}}(\boldsymbol{x}_1)\Delta \delta_{e,2} & \Phi^T_{G_{22}}(\boldsymbol{x}_1) \Delta \delta_{a,2} & \Phi^T_{G_{23}}(\boldsymbol{x}_1) \Delta \delta_{r,2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\\ 
\Phi^T_{G_{21}}(\boldsymbol{x}_{N-1})\Delta \delta_{e,N} & \Phi^T_{G_{22}}(\boldsymbol{x}_{N-1}) \Delta \delta_{a,N} & \Phi^T_{G_{23}}(\boldsymbol{x}_{N-1}) \Delta \delta_{r,N}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta_{G_{21}} \\ 
\Theta_{G_{22}}\\ 
\Theta_{G_{23}}
\end{bmatrix} \,.$

However, I doubt whether this notation is correct (especially the matrix containing $D_2$).

Answer (score 0):

The size of the left side of your equation is $3N \times 1$, so we need the right hand side to be the same.

Right hand side: The first term is $3N\times 3$, the second term is $3N \times 18$ and the third term is $18 \times 1$, which isn't correct.

First guess would be to make the first matrix a diagonal matrix with $D_2(x_i)$ on the diagonal and the rest of the entries $3\times 3$ zero matrices. Haven't worked this out, but seems correct. That would at least give you the correct dimensions: diagonal matrix is $3N\times 3N$.